# Best book for contest maths.

Tags: reference-request, contest-math

Can anyone please suggest me any good book for contest maths which has both theory and problems. I am a beginner in this area of maths but i feel that I have an ability to learn and absorb concepts quickly. I don't want any competition specific book as I just want to increase my knowledge and skills of problem solving. It will be great help if you do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are topics you want to cover?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question  because you asked it here and it was closed as too broad:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3358306/best-book-for-contest-maths . Perhaps if you [edit] the question and tell us more about what level you are interested in and what competition you plan to enter we may be able to make some suggestions. For general problem solving, try Polya's "How to Solve It".

Comment: Why down-voting? Contest math questions are all of the same nature. So it should not be too broad.

Answer (score 1):

A very good book is Problem-Solving Strategies of Arthur Engel, another one is Problem-Solving through problems of Loren C. Larson!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest "concrete mathematics", written by Ronald Graham, Donald Knuth, and Oren Patashnik. It was originally written for computer science practioners, but it really helped with approaching mathematical problems. Good luck!